# Merge identical format dictionaries into one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert the **Current data format** into **Expected result**

The items should be ordered as origin.

How could I do it in elegant way with Python

### Current data format

```
[{'_id': 1800, 'count': 32},
 .....
 {'_id': 1892, 'count': 1},
 {'_id': 1899, 'count': 13}]
```

### Expected result

```
 {"_id":[1800,1892,1899], "count":[32,1,13]}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: I don't see how this question is a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [{'_id': 1800, 'count': 32},
 {'_id': 1892, 'count': 1},
 {'_id': 1899, 'count': 13}]

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
    for j,k in i.items():
        d[j].append(k)

>>>d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'count': [32, 1, 13], '_id': [1800, 1892, 1899]})
```

**OR**

using `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

l = [{i:[j] for i,j in d.items()} for d in l]
result_counter = Counter()
for i in l:
    result_counter.update(i)

>>>result_counter
Counter({'_id': [1800, 1892, 1899], 'count': [32, 1, 13]})
```

Answer (score 1):

From [python collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) docs:

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply traverse the list and construct the required dictionary.

```
In [2]: l = [{'_id': 1800, 'count': 32}, {'_id': 1892, 'count': 1}, {'_id': 1899, 'count': 13}]

In [3]: {'_id': [data['_id'] for data in l], 'count': [data['count'] for data in l]}
Out[3]: {'_id': [1800, 1892, 1899], 'count': [32, 1, 13]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data
[{'count': 32, '_id': 1800}, {'count': 1, '_id': 1892}, {'count': 13, '_id': 1899}]
>>> result = {key:[] for key in data[0]}
>>> for d in data:
...     for k in d:
...         result[k].append(d[k])
... 
>>> result
{'count': [32, 1, 13], '_id': [1800, 1892, 1899]}
```